# Python Django (static files/change ip server)

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have one problem. When i change ip adress for server, then my css (Bootstrap) don't work.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'Project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^home/', 'Blog.views.my_blog')
)

if settings.DEBUG == True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head lang="ru">
        <title> Savichev's site </title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href={% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

What's wrong ?
CSS work correctly only on ip 127.0.0.1:8000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, with the little information you gave us, you need to provide a `STATIC_ROOT` variable in your `settings.py`.

Comment: But i haven't this variable

Comment: So create it, do something like `STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'`